# How do I properly/securely store an OAuth token in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, security, database-design, oauth, cryptography

I have a PostgreSQL database, and a web app where users authenticate over OAuth 2.0, providing me with an access token and a refresh token. I need to store both of these to continue to allow them access to the web service.

How do I store these effectively? Unlike with passwords I can't hash them, because I need to be able to read them to pass with requests.

Comment: Why store them at all? Once authenticated you know they are allowed to access the database.

Comment: @Patrick I need to store them in order to make the API calls. It's not only for authentication, it's to be passed with every additional call as well to prove. Think of a web app that manages Twitter accounts for instance.